# JQuery Disable after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I'm sorry for asking a question that there seems to be TONS of info on, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I'm simply trying to stop a double form submission from happening, I'm using the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>   
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cc_form").submit(function() {
    if ($.data($("#cc_form").get(0), 'submitting')) {
        return false;
     }
     $.data($("#cc_form").get(0), 'submitting', true);
     $(".submit",$("#cc_form")).prop('disabled', true);
});     
});
</script>
```

It works fine in FF 4 and FF 5, it does not work in IE 8 or IE 9. In IE I get that "Object Expected" on the document.ready line. I've tried moving it from the head to just before the closing body, I tried using `type=text/javascript` and `language=javascript`, I've tried using `jQuery(function()..` instead of `document.ready` and no matter what I tried I get that error in IE and it does not stop multiple form submissions (while FF continues to work without any error).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try clearing the cache, maybe there is an broken jquery.js in IE's cache.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been clearing the cache every time and have used multiple browsers on multiple machines and still have the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying this on a webserver? Otherwise the script-path starting with / will not work like expected. To be sure that this problem is not caused by your jquery-version, check if it works with loading jquery from a cdn, e.g. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js

Comment: Yep, its running on apache and like I said, it works fine in FF and if I just try to load the jquery-1.6.1.min.js directly in IE I see it using the same path.

Comment: Have you looked into `preventDefault()`? That's what I generally use to prevent form shenanigans. Though I am still slightly unclear as to what it is you are trying to do. Can you post your markup?

Comment: I'm all set - I don't know what to say. Just to try something different I downloaded the uncompressed version and it WORKED!. I then download the min again and even though they are the same to the byte on the filesystem, it worked! Doesn't make any sense but thanks all for the help!

Comment: @Analog you can add that as an answer to your own question :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know what else to do. I forgot my old login so I'm using my google one now and as this was my 1st post, I couldn't answer my own question. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing jumps out at me:

```
$(".submit",$("#cc_form")).prop('disabled', true);
```

Give this a shot:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>   
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var cc_form = $("#cc_form");
cc_form.submit(function() {
    if ($.data(this, 'submitting')) {
        return false;
     }
     $.data(this, 'submitting', true);
     $(".submit, #cc_form").attr('disabled', true); // Revert to .prop() if this is a working solution per comments
});     
});
</script>
```

Comment: prop also has issues with IE7/8, no?

Comment: Thanks Melee, no change though, I still get the same IE Object error and it doesn't stop multiple submissions (but it does still work in FF).

Comment: @user823323 ahh shucks. You should make a jsfiddle of it and I can try some other things.

Comment: @melee As far as i know, no. also you don't need to use 'cc_form.get(0)', because context for onsubmit handler is the form itself, so you can easily write 'this'.

Comment: durf. Thanks for the audit @Beygi

Comment: @melee In Internet Explorer prior to version 9, using .prop() to set a DOM element property to **anything other than a simple primitive value** (number, string, or boolean) can cause memory leaks if the property is not removed.

Comment: @melee this itself equals to cc_form.get(0)

Comment: @Beygi one more thing - how could I modify `$(".submit, #cc_form")` to include the cached selector?

Comment: @melee you mean that you want to have the cached '#cc_form' in another selector like this '$(".submit, ...")'

Comment: @melee if i understand you correctly then you need the 'add' method

Answer (score 0):

I'm all set - I don't know what to say. Just to try something different I downloaded the uncompressed version and it WORKED!. I then download the min again and even though they are the same to the byte on the filesystem, it worked!